# Django: Force users to re-login

Tags: django, authentication

I would like to know how I can force users to re-login in django?

My situation is the following: I'm developing  have a facebook app, where I store some of their data.

As sometimes, it's expensive (time consuming) to update all users info, I don't do it at every access, but only when they login.

Sometimes, I do want to re-update their data to store new available data or even data due to new permissions, so I would like a way to force them to re-login. This will be done eventually, so no need for automation.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the Session table. Their sessions are stored there and once they return to site they'll have to login again.